# CSS opacity transition won't work for Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to implement some kind of lazy background image loading. I want the image to fade in as soon as it's loaded. Therefore I change the holding div's opacity on load. **It work's for Chrome or Firefox, but somehow not for Safari.** Using Safari the images just appear without any transition. How so?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import './ImageHolder.css'

class LazyImage extends Component {

    state = {
        src: null,
    };

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {

        if (prevProps.image !== this.props.image) {
            this.setState({src: null});
            this.loadImage();
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadImage();
    }

    loadImage = () => {
        const src = this.props.image;

        const imageLoader = new Image();
        imageLoader.src = src;

        imageLoader.onload = () => {
            this.setState({src: src})
        };
    };

    classList = (classes) => {
        return Object
            .entries(classes)
            .filter(entry => entry[1])
            .map(entry => entry[0])
            .join(' ');
    };

    render() {
        const style = {
            backgroundImage: 'url(' + this.state.src + ')',
        };

        return(
            <div className="h-image-wrapper" style={{backgroundColor: this.props.bgColor}}>
                <div className={this.classList({
                    'h-image-holder': true,
                    'h-image-loaded': this.state.src,
                })} style={style} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LazyImage;
```

```
.h-image-holder {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    will-change: opacity, transform;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: opacity .6s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .6s ease;
}

.h-image-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    will-change: transform;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.h-image-loaded {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help.
On the [Safari CSS Visual Effects Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/AnimatingCSSTransitions/AnimatingCSSTransitions.html) it's says that you have to use this:

```
-webkit-transition-property: opacity;
```

You can also change the duration of it doing:

```
-webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
```

And the easing function:

```
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
```

Answer (score -1):

it is noted [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/AnimatingCSSTransitions/AnimatingCSSTransitions.html)

> Note: Not all CSS properties are animatable. In general, any CSS property that accepts values that are numbers, lengths, percentages, or colors is animatable. Some CSS properties that accept discrete values can be animated as well, but display a jump between values rather than a smooth transition when changed, such as the visibility property.

[Safari CSS Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002050)